# Source file not available anymore

Tags: mariadb, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm facing something new in my experience. An updated Yocto environment fails to build while fetching `MariaDB`:

```
WARNING: mariadb-5.5.64-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: mariadb-5.5.64-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-BIEhFRRkoA"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/osboxes"; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/downloads 'https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 8, output:
--2019-11-03 12:10:45--  https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz
Resolving downloads.mariadb.org (downloads.mariadb.org)... 116.203.207.31, 2a01:4f8:c2c:b04e::1
Connecting to downloads.mariadb.org (downloads.mariadb.org)|116.203.207.31|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/mariadb.org//mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz [following]
--2019-11-03 12:10:46--  http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/mariadb.org//mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.hosteurope.de (ftp.hosteurope.de)... 80.237.136.138, 2a01:488:10:1::50ed:888a
Connecting to ftp.hosteurope.de (ftp.hosteurope.de)|80.237.136.138|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-11-03 12:10:46 ERROR 404: Not Found.


ERROR: mariadb-5.5.64-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: mariadb-5.5.64-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/mariadb/5.5.64-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.11382
ERROR: Task (/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-dbs/mysql/mariadb_5.5.64.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

Now I see the URLs are hardcoded into: `layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-dbs/mysql/mariadb.inc`:

```
SUMMARY = "A robust, scalable, and reliable SQL server"
HOMEPAGE = "http://mariadb.org"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=751419260aa954499f7abaabaa882bbe"

SRC_URI = "https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/${BP}/source/${BP}.tar.gz \
           file://fix-cmake-module-path.patch \
           file://remove-bad-path.patch \
           file://fix-mysqlclient-r-version.patch \
           file://my.cnf \
           file://mysqld.service \
           file://install_db.service \
           file://install_db \
           file://mysql-systemd-start \
           file://configure.cmake-fix-valgrind.patch \
           file://fix-a-building-failure.patch \
           file://change-cc-to-cc-version.patch \
           file://0001-disable-ucontext-on-musl.patch \
          "
```

Hence, I tried to retrieve the same file (`mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz`) on the Internet and I found this:

> https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/mariadb-5.5.64/source/mariadb-5.5.64.tar.gz/from/http%3A//ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.mariadb.org/?serve

that seems very close to the one above, but the working one has another path as suffix.

I don't understand if they (the `mariadb` maintainers) changed the URLs or there is an error in the `meta-openembedded` recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maintainers of FOSS software, in this case the MariaDB Foundation, usually don't make promises that download URLS will remain unchanged.  MariaDB uses a scheme to help downloaders find a nearby mirror site, and that's what you found.

Those mirrorfinders rely on stuff like http redirect operations. Browsers are good at handling those operations. Downloading code built into other programs may not be.

You may find it helpful to edit that URL in that recipe to point to the exact ftp file you need. It appears to be in this ftp folder.

```
http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.64/source/
```

Comment: Actually editing the file did the trick - thanks. I just wonder if it's a correct approach or I have to override that variable in another file (like `*.bbappend` files do).