# Remove packagegroup from image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

[I have problems fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680247/source-file-not-available-anymore) `MariaDB`. Because I don't need this package I'm trying to remove it. First, I tried to understand what include it:

```
$ grep -nrw ../layers/ -e mariadb
Binary file ../layers/meta-openembedded/.git/index matches
../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-meta-oe.bb:99:    leveldb libdbi mariadb mariadb-native \
```

Looking into `packagegroup-meta-oe.bb` I found:

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs ="\
    leveldb libdbi mariadb mariadb-native \
    mysql-python postgresql psqlodbc rocksdb soci \
    sqlite \
    ${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "bluez4", "mongodb", "", d)} \
    "
```

hence I tried to remove `packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs` in my `<image>.bb`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs"
```

But it still insists to build it.
Where is my fault?

Comment: If you just hack on `packagegroup-meta-oe.bb` and simply remove `mariadb` is everything good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs` is a runtime dependency of `packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs`, you cannot remove it without removing `packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs`.

What you need to do is create bbappend for `packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs`, and add the following line to it:

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs_remove = "mariadb"
```

Comment: You could also add the line to local.conf instead of creating a new bbappend file. 

RDEPENDS_packagegroup-meta-oe-dbs_remove = "mariadb"